# Set taxons in products using Spree Commerce API

Tags: ruby, api, product, spree, taxonomy

This code don't works to set taxons in products using Spree Commerce API.
WThe product is returned without taxons. Why?

```
    product_params = {
        "product[taxon_ids][]" => taxon_id,
        "product[available_on]" => product_available_on
    }
    post_product_update = client.put("/api/products/#{product_id}", product_params)
```

The response is ... "taxon_ids": [], ... ( http://pastebin.com/ZJVqRLs8 )

SOLVED: "product[taxon_ids]" => taxon_id OR "product[taxon_ids]" => taxon_id, taxon_id,...

Comment: What's the response?

Comment: The response is: http://pastebin.com/ZJVqRLs8

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the data you sent to spree and the output in the spree logs I can't tell what happened to you but you can add taxons to a products by using `product[taxon_ids][]=taxon_id` in your POST parameter.

Here is an example with curl

```
curl -X POST -d "product[name]=TEST&product[price]=100&product[shipping_category_id]=1&product[taxon_ids][]=14&product[taxon_ids][]=15" -H "X-Spree-Token: TOKEN" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products
```

This adds the product to taxon 14 and 15.